# Even after installing cvzone Im unable to import HandDetector from cvzone.HandTrackingModule

Tags: python, opencv, cvzone

import cv2
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector

web_cam= cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:

```
success,img = web_cam.read()
img = cv2.flip(img,1)

#display image
cv2.imshow('Image', img)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem as you did, even after I checked the interpreter and installed *cvzone* through the command 'pip install cvzone', when I tried to run import *cvzone*, it still disregarded the *cvzone*. I believe this could be the problem of the environmental path.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).